# calculating time gap between purchases (datetime variable with NAs)

Tags: r, datetime-format

`df` is a data frame which shows visits and time of purchase for different customers.

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
visit<-rep("yes",11)
purchase<-c("2015-04-27 13:57:06","2015-04-27 13:59:19","2015-04-27  14:03:35","NA","NA","2015-04-27 16:59:42","2015-05-18 17:01:09","2015-05-18 17:03:40","2015-05-18 17:04:00","NA","NA") 
df<-data.frame(id,visit,purchase)
```

when the `purchase` variable is `NA` it means that the customer has visited the website but did not make a purchase.

Now I need a create a new variable called `time.gap` to calculate the time gap between purchases for each customer as follow:

```
   id visit            purchase time.gap
1   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:57:06       NA
2   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:59:19      133
3   1   yes 2015-04-27 14:03:35      256
4   1   yes                  NA       NA
5   1   yes                  NA       NA
6   1   yes 2015-04-27 16:59:42    10567
7   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:01:09       NA
8   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:03:40      151
9   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:04:00       20
10  2   yes                  NA       NA
11  2   yes                  NA       NA
```

Would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$purchase <- strptime(df$purchase, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df1 <- df

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(purchase)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time.gap = c(NA, difftime(purchase[-1], 
                                   purchase[-length(purchase)], units="secs"))) %>%
  left_join(df1, .)
#    id visit            purchase time.gap
# 1   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:57:06       NA
# 2   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:59:19      133
# 3   1   yes 2015-04-27 14:03:35      256
# 4   1   yes                <NA>       NA
# 5   1   yes                <NA>       NA
# 6   1   yes 2015-04-27 16:59:42    10567
# 7   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:01:09       NA
# 8   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:03:40      151
# 9   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:04:00       20
# 10  2   yes                <NA>       NA
# 11  2   yes                <NA>       NA
```

This is a `dplyr` approach with a merge added in. And `difftime` used instead of `diff` since it allows a units argument.

**Data**

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
visit<-rep("yes",11)
purchase<-c("2015-04-27 13:57:06","2015-04-27 13:59:19","2015-04-27  14:03:35","NA","NA","2015-04-27 16:59:42","2015-05-18 17:01:09","2015-05-18 17:03:40","2015-05-18 17:04:00","NA","NA") 
df<-data.frame(id,visit,purchase) 
is.na(df$purchase) <- df$purchase == "NA"
df$purchase <- as.POSIXct(df$purchase)
```

**Troubleshooting**

If you run into problems with your real data, we can isolate where the issue is coming from with a test:

```
s <- split(df, df$id)
test <- list()
for(i in 1:length(s)) {
  s1 <- s[[i]]
test[[i]] <- s[[i]] %>% 
  filter(!is.na(purchase)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time.gap = c(NA, difftime(purchase[-1], 
                                   purchase[-length(purchase)], units="secs"))) %>%
  left_join(s1, .)

}
```

Now `test` is a list with all of the iterations of the code. If an error is thrown we will know where it happened because all of the other successful runs will be saved. So if I get an error and look at `test` and it has all of the ids up to id `3`, I know that id `4` caused the error.

Comment: Your codes perfectly work on this example but when I run them on my working data it returns the following error: incompatible size (16737151), expecting 47 (the group size) or 1. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: I tried out different scenarios, I can't reproduce the error. You will have to troubleshoot your data. Try splitting the data by id `s <- split(df, df$id)` and run the code on each id `test <- list(); for (i in 1:length(s)) test[[i]] <- **our above code**`. When the error message comes up, you will know which id created it because the last entry for `test` will be the last successful turn.

Comment: btw replace all of the `df` in the code with `s` when you test it.

Comment: Apparently the problem is in my real data instead of NA the cells are blank and the code is terminated when reaches the first blank cell.

Comment: Use `is.na(df) <- df == ""` before doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that time gap for each user id will need an additional step, grouping at id level.

-EDITED missed the date conversion.

A very concise approach with `dplyr` lubridate and `zoo`

```
# libraries
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

# the data
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
visit<-rep("yes",11)
purchase<-c("2015-04-27 13:57:06","2015-04-27 13:59:19","2015-04-27 14:03:35","NA","NA","2015-04-27 16:59:42","2015-05-18 17:01:09","2015-05-18 17:03:40","2015-05-18 17:04:00","NA","NA") 
df<-data.frame(id,visit,purchase) 
df$purchase <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$purchase)
# helper column
df$purch <- zoo::na.locf(df$purchase)
df

#> df
#   id visit            purchase               purch
#1   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:57:06 2015-04-27 13:57:06
#2   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:59:19 2015-04-27 13:59:19
#3   1   yes 2015-04-27 14:03:35 2015-04-27 14:03:35
#4   1   yes                <NA> 2015-04-27 14:03:35
#5   1   yes                <NA> 2015-04-27 14:03:35
#6   1   yes 2015-04-27 16:59:42 2015-04-27 16:59:42
#7   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:01:09 2015-05-18 17:01:09
#8   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:03:40 2015-05-18 17:03:40
#9   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:04:00 2015-05-18 17:04:00
#10  2   yes                <NA> 2015-05-18 17:04:00
#11  2   yes                <NA> 2015-05-18 17:04:00

# run it
df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(dif=c(NA, diff(purch)))%>%
  select(-purch)

#Source: local data frame [11 x 4]
#Groups: id
#
#   id visit            purchase   dif
#1   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:57:06    NA
#2   1   yes 2015-04-27 13:59:19   133
#3   1   yes 2015-04-27 14:03:35   256
#4   1   yes                <NA>     0
#5   1   yes                <NA>     0
#6   1   yes 2015-04-27 16:59:42 10567
#7   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:01:09    NA
#8   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:03:40   151
#9   2   yes 2015-05-18 17:04:00    20
#10  2   yes                <NA>     0
#11  2   yes                <NA>     0
```

OR with a one shot

```
df%>%
  mutate(purch=zoo::na.locf(lubridate::ymd_hms(df$purchase))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dif=c(NA, diff(purch))) %>%
  select(-purch)

# packages [1] lubridate_1.3.3 zoo_1.7-12      dplyr_0.4.2
```

Comment: Check your output vs the expected

Comment: @Paulo the problem is with line 6 where it fails to give the time gap.

Comment: Tried it but does not give me the output you have presented.

Comment: @AliTamaddoni. Sorry. I forgot a piece of code, to convert your dates to POSIXct.